# assigning values to structure of a class using class object

Tags: c++, class, object, struct

I have got a very strange problem.
Here is my code:
Header File

```
namespace test
{
class LoadConfigData
{

    struct control_params
    {
         char               active[];
         char               suspended[];
         char               erased[];        
    }*ctrl_params;
bool loadConfig();
};
};
```

Main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
using namespace test;
namespace test
{
extern LoadConfigData           *loadConfigDataobj;
LoadConfigData *loadConfigDataobj   = new LoadConfigData;
};
int main()
{
loadConfigDataobj->loadConfig();
cout <<loadConfigDataobj->ctrl_params->active_status_code_v<<endl;
cout <<loadConfigDataobj->ctrl_params->suspended_status_code_v<<endl;
cout <<loadConfigDataobj->ctrl_params->erase_status_code_v<<endl;
return 0;
}

bool LoadConfigData::loadConfig()
{
std::string a = "AC";
std::string b = "SP";
std::string c = "ER";
LoadConfigData::ctrl_params = new LoadConfigData::control_params;
sprintf(loadConfigDataobj->ctrl_params->active,"%s",a.c_str());
sprintf(loadConfigDataobj->ctrl_params->suspended,"%s",b.c_str());
sprintf(loadConfigDataobj->ctrl_params->erased,"%s",c.c_str());
return true;
}
```

Output:

```
ER
ER
ER
```

Which means that it's printing the last copied string for each struct member.
What is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't give the character arrays a size:

```
struct control_params
{
     char               active[];
     char               suspended[];
     char               erased[];        
}*ctrl_params;
```

I'm rather surprised that this compiles; my understanding was that an unsized array was an incomplete type, and so couldn't be a non-static class member. However, my compiler at least (and presumably yours) treats these as arrays of size zero, all at the same location in memory. Therefore, each time you write to one it overwrites whatever you wrote to the others. (Of course, the behaviour is undefined since it writes outside the array bounds).

The simplest solution is to use `std::string` to represent the strings. That will manage its size automatically, and you can simply write `active = a` rather than messing around with `sprintf` (or, slightly more sensibly, `strncpy`) and hoping you don't get a buffer overrun.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. It was the problem with unsized array. Defining the size solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @sajal: Do you know exactly what you are doing? Are you sure the strings will always be big enough? Why not _just_ use `std::string`? If those are really configuration data, you prolly do not have control about the input-length, and then you will have safety issues that any cracker will welcome. How much about string-function-vulnerabilities do you know? Please, have a deep read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_vulnerabilities , especially (but totally not exclusively) about buffer overflows and format string attacks. I seriously hope this is not production code and just for learning.

Comment: @phresnel: Thanks a lot for your concern. The code which I have mentioned here is not the same as what I am using. I am fetching data from database for which I have to use a specific library which returns the data in form of char array and then I am storing it in control_params. I know the string size and hence it will work now. But yes, if the string size changes later on, I will have no other option other than changing the code.

Comment: @sajal: Your DB API can change and it will change. You will have forgotten about your char arrays then. You will then be lucky if the program segfaults. But possibly it will run for months, and only at your highest feast, it will suddenly segfault, and cost you money and reputation. Better use string from the beginning on.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your usage of `sprintf`. `sprintf` will not allocate any memory for you, `active`, `suspended` and `erased` are pointing to strange and undefined addresses. You are invoking undefined behaviour.

Without adding all the normally necessary detail, use `std::string` and it's operator overloads instead. For simple parsing, use streams. For now, totally avoid any C-string-function, and instead use C++ solely.